# Structuring Google Cloud Platform project

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

I'm working on a project that has many small tasks. Some of these tasks are related and require overlapping apis.

```
task_1/
    main.py
task_2/
    main.py
apis/
    api_1/
    api_2/
    api_3/
test/
    test_api_1.py
    test_api_2.py
    test_task_1.py
    test_task_2.py
    test_task_3.py
```

For example, `task_1` needs `api_1` and `api_3`, while `task_2` needs `api_1` and `api_2`. At first I tried using Google Cloud Functions to execute these tasks, but I ran into the issue that [GCF needs local dependencies installed in the same folder as the task](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python#packaging_local_dependencies). This would mean duplicating the code from `api_1` into `task_1`. Further, local testing would become more complicated because of the way GCF does imports (opposed to `.mylocalpackage.myscript`):

> You can then use code from the local dependency, mylocalpackage:
>
> `from mylocalpackage.myscript import foo`

Is there a way to structure my codebase to enable easier deployment of GCF? Due to my requirements, I cannot deploy each API as its own GCF. Will Google Cloud Run remedy my issues?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To use Cloud Functions for this, you will need to arrange your code in such a way that all the code a function depends on is present within that function's directory at the time of deployment. This might be done as a custom build/packaging step to move files around.

To use Cloud Run for this, you need to create a minimal HTTP webserver to route requests to each of your "functions". This might be best done by creating a path for each function you want to support. At that point, you've recreated a traditional web service with multiple resources.

If these tasks were meant as [Background Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background), you can [wire up Pub/Sub Push integration](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/pubsub).